# No adapter for handler with spring-boot custom starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I am developing a spring-boot custom starter, and I want my components/beans to be initialized only if some conditions are met. These beans include a REST controller. I have made a `@Configuration` class for that purpose:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Conditional(MyConditions.class)
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping registerController() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();

        Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();

        urlMap.put("/custom", myController());

        handlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);

        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyController myController() {
        return new MyController();
    }
```

`MyController` class is:

```
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "I'm here";
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that `localhost:8080/custom` answers *I'm here*, but instead of that what I get is:

`No adapter for handler [MyController@355b46cb]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler","path":"/custom"`

I don't want any of my beans to be initialized if conditions are not met, that is why `MyController` is not annotated with `@Controller` or `@RestController`.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

**Note**: to test this, I have created a minimalistic SpringBoot project with a controller and I have added my custom starter as a dependency. `MyConfiguration` conditions are matched and beans are registered.

Comment: Are these conditions are passed on startup? if so, you can achieve that using Profiles

Comment: The conditions for the Configuration class to be proccessed are met. If not the application would return a 404.

Comment: What are theses conditions ?!

Comment: The conditions are not the problem, other beans declared in that class are working fine, the only problem is the controller.